# WAMP error! 403 forbidden after i installed laravel

Tags: localhost, wamp

Good day! i just started learning laravel, watched a tutorial on how to install it..it had me to edit the httd.conf file, the vhost and the host in the system32 to create a virtual host and make a pretty url (i made laravel.dev)..but now when i type localhost on my web browser it says wamp error! forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

in my httpd.conf file i uncommented

```
       # Virtual hosts
        Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

here is what i added in my httpd-vhost.conf

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
          DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/laravel-test/public
            ServerName laravel2.dev
        </VirtualHost>
```

hosts file in my system32/drivers/etc

```
          127.0.0.1 localhost
          127.0.0.2 laravel2.dev
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a correct configuration of the WampServer virtual host

First you should create a VH for localhost, so that localhost still works properly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All

        Require local

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you create a Virtual Hosts for this Laravel testing site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/laravel-test/public"
    ServerName laravel2.dev
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/laravel-test/public">
        AllowOverride all

        Require local

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice that both VH Definitions contain a `<Directory>....</Directory>` block, this is the section of the VH definition where you tell Apache who is allowed to access this Virtual Host.

Because you had no such acceess control statements Apache assumed Nobody was allowed to access this site.

Also your HOSTS file should look like this :-

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 laravel2.dev

::1   localhost
::1   laravel2.dev
```

Comment: I've also noticed this error if you mistakenly use backslashes rather than forward slashes when specifying the directory paths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure all these complicated solutions have their place, but if they still don't work ...

> > #### Just go to laravel.dev/public or localhost/laravel/public
> >
> > > You can also update your document root to "Laravel_install_name/public"